# Ant equivalent of nant.onsuccess / nant.onfailure

Tags: ant, error-handling, nant

NAnt has two [built-in properties](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/fundamentals/properties.html#built-in-properties), `nant.onsuccess` and `nant.onfailure`, for specifying tasks to run on success and failure respectively.

Is there an equivalent in Ant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an ant equivalent but you could use [trycatch](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html) (part of ant-contrib)

```
<trycatch>
  <try>
    <!-- Your code here -->
    <!-- Success message -->
  </try>
  <catch>
    <!-- Fail message -->
  </catch>
</trycatch>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Kev Jackson, gave a neat example of an exec-listener in
his presentation, =
http://people.apache.org/~kevj/ossummit/extending-ant.html,
the sources of the exec-listener are included

You're able to kick off specific tasks depending
on the build result after your build has finished.

```
<exec-listener onSuccess="true|false">
 ..

your stuff goes here
..
</exec-listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I've marked John McG as the answer (as it's what I've gone with), I've also discovered that it's also possible to build similar functionality using [BuildListeners](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/BuildListener.html).